# Start cmd.exe on new Process then user Scanner on it

Tags: java

Is there a way to open a `cmd.exe` via `ProcessBuilder` and then reference its streams such that one could call `NewProcessOutputStream.println()` and `Scanner s = new Scanner(NewProcessInputStream)`?

I am aware that I can issue a command such as `cmd /c dir` and read the input stream, but I would like to open the `cmd` process, then access its streams such that I can print to it whenever.

Is what I am thinking of possible? Or should I be executing another program via the process?

**Edit (Updated): Output not what expected**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Terminal {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Process cmd = new ProcessBuilder("cmd").start();

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(cmd.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmd.getInputStream()));

        writer.println("Hello");
        writer.println("World!");
        writer.println("How are you?");
        writer.close();

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\temp\CLI\src>java Terminal
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\temp\CLI\src>Hello

C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\temp\CLI\src>World!

C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\temp\CLI\src>How are you?

C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\temp\CLI\src>

C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\temp\CLI\src>
```

Comment: [Reader.ready() does not do what you think it does.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready--)  To check for the end of input, check whether readLine() returns null.

Comment: you want to print from the parent Java process to the terminal window?

Comment: @VGR Please see my update to my edit. Changing the `while` worked, but what I want to do produces a very different result.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer I want to start a terminal, write to it as if I was calling `System.out.println(someString)` and then be able to read the results of what was printed.

Comment: What's output are you expecting from your example?

Comment: @pablochan The same as if I were calling each `writer.println` as `System.out.println`. The `System.out` refers to the output stream of the process running the current `java Terminal`; how do I start another one for writing to just the same?

Comment: I still don’t understand what you’re trying to do.  cmd.exe doesn’t print anything unless you execute an actual command in the shell, like `echo`.  Are you trying to force cmd.exe to execute implicit `echo` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the process input using [`Process.getOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()) and its output using [`Process.getInputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()).

Here's an example:

```
public class ProcessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process grep = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "foo").start();

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(grep.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(grep.getInputStream()));

        writer.println("this is the first line");
        writer.println("this is the foo line");
        writer.println("this is the last line");
        writer.println("nope, another foo");
        writer.close();

        // EDIT: fixed end of stream check
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please see my edit. Nothing happens. I think what I need to do is issue a program to `cmd` for it to run and in that program, access the input/output streams for printing and receiving input/output. Even when I copy your code word for word, nothing happens in the command prompt when I issue `java Terminal`.